# Moving content of custom header Magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom, header

[image: This is how the header is displayed]

I created a custom header and called it in the default.xml
this is the code

```
<referenceContainer name="header.container">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom_header" as="custom_header" template="Magento_Theme::html/customheader.phtml"  before="-" />
</referenceContainer>

        <move element="minicart" destination="custom_header"/>
        <move element="top.search" destination="custom_header"/>
        <move element="logo" as="logo" destination="custom_header"/>
```

I want to move the content to the empty black area
I'm using Magento 2.2.5 
Thanks

Comment: Did you try my solution ? If any issue please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to community.

If you want to add a custom `Reference Container` You can add following code at

> app/design/frontend/[Package]/[theme]/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">

<referenceContainer name="header.container">
    <container name="custom_header" as="custom_header" label="My Custom Header" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="my-container" before="page.top"/>
</referenceContainer>

    <move element="minicart" destination="custom_header"/>
    <move element="top.search" destination="custom_header"/>
    <move element="logo" as="logo" destination="custom_header"/>
```

Above code will create a new container and move element to that.

**Note** For adding new container you can use `after` `before`.

Comment: Hello @Aissa,above solution worked for you ? Or do you need further help ?