# <referenceBlock name="header.container" remove="true" /> removes minicart functionality

Tags: knockoutjs, requirejs, magento2.4, theme-overriding, default.xml

I've added `<referenceBlock name="header.container" remove="true" />` to my themes `default.xml` and instead has been replaced with:

```
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
    <block  class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" 
            name="top.header" 
            template="Magento_Theme::html/custom_header.phtml" 
            before="header.container"
    />
</referenceContainer>
```

But, by doing this I lose all of the minicart functionality. The JS is not added. This is a problem for me because when I attempt to get the cart total like so:

```
<div data-bind="scope: 'minicart_counter'">
    <span data-bind="html: getCartParamUnsanitizedHtml('summary_count')"></span>
</div>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                    "minicart_counter": {
                        "component": "Magento_Checkout/js/view/minicart"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I get an error:

```
console-output-handler.js:34 [2020-11-12 10:34:54] [ERROR] Failed to load the 
"Magento_Checkout/js/view/minicart" component.
```

But if I make the `header.container` visible with `<referenceBlock name="header.container" remove="false" />` my custom header shows the cart quantity total ... except I now have two headers showing (the default one and my custom).

I've battled with this for hours to no avail. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried moving? https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/240662/70343

Comment: Why do you want to remove it and then add you custom? Just modify it, or add and remove what you need. What you want to accomplish with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm fairly certain the minicart is nested within the `header.container` block. So you'll want to find the exact block or container within `header.container` and perform your customization on that.

[image: Screenshot of the layout tree of the default magento store with Luma theme]

Comment: How did you get that list of containers and blocks?

Comment: This extension. https://github.com/vpietri/magento2-developer-quickdevbar

Comment: I did not know this plugin existed. Thank you for sharing the link!

Comment: sure thing, it's been a very useful tool for me as well.